# Configuring ssh runner for gitlab ssh denied

Tags: ssh, continuous-integration, gitlab, handshake, runner

I'm trying to set up a simple gitlab CI for an angular project

I just made a runner on staging server.

Here is an extract of config.toml in /etc/gitlab-runner

```
  name = "awsTest10"
  url = "http://gitlab.XXXXXXX/ci"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "root"
    host = "ec2-XX-XX-XX-XX.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/root/.ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
```

I created a ssh key with root and I copied the public part in gitlab deploys keys. I made ssh-add before.

When I use the runner I have the following result :

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.11.1 (a67a225)
  on awsTest10 (e1ce142d)
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you try with a key without passphrase (so no need for ssh-agent)?

Comment: I 've no passphrase

Comment: Then ssh-gent is not involved. Is the runner running as root?

Comment: Yes it is, the config.toml is in the root folder.

Comment: Maybe you did not restart sshd after changes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I appended public key to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and uncomment `AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` line in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. Then i restarted ssh service and it works for me.